# php tricker a reload of webpage (with resend of data)

Tags: php, post, reload

I've got a form split on three pages. Each page submits to the next page. Now I need to place a language selector so the form can be reloaded midway in a new language.

Problem: When posting language selector (form) then old post vars are deleted.

How can I change language without loosing old postvars? Just like hitting f5?

Comment: I think you accidentally tagged PGP instead of PHP.

Comment: Use hidden fields (<input type="hidden"...>) OR submit data by GET request OR store data for user in a session and set a cookie